# How to create temporary alias for a parameter to a pass by name function argument?

Tags: scala

Notice in the following [code](https://ideone.com/XTvJqY), "Hello" is printed twice in `test1()` but only once in `test2()`.

Assuming I can't change change `f()` and `g()`, how can I change `test2()` so it behaves like `test1()`, whilst retaining the ability to give the expression an alias (in this case `x`)?

Basically I'm looking for a transformation from `test1()` to something like `test2()` that doesn't change the meaning of the code in anycase.

```
object Main extends App {
    println("test1")
    println(test1())
    println("test2")
    println(test2())

    def test1() : Int = {
        f(g())
    }
    
    def test2() : Int = {
        lazy val x = g()
        f(x)
    }
    
    def g() : Int = { 
        println("Hello") 
        42 
    }
    
    def f(x: => Int) : Int = {
        x * x
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `def` rather than `val`:

```
def test2(): Int = {
    def x = g()
    f(x)
}
```